# Need help getting data from website using importxml and xpath

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would like to have some help to get the data beside ROE from this link using importxml / xpath. http://fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=TAEE11 ... so in this case the ROE data is 20,8% . I would like to get this value using importxml / xpath.

How to do that? I've tried some formulas but.. not able to get the details from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of importxml, match and index:

```
=index(IMPORTXML("http://fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=TAEE11","//*[@class='txt']"),match("roe",IMPORTXML("http://fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=TAEE11","//*[@class='txt']"),0)+1,0)
```

Basically what is happening is that by point to the class @ txt it stacks all the labels above the data fields, so you can consistently search for a label such as ROE, and just increase the index by 1 to retrieve the corresponding value.

[image]